# Sort cells inside a tableview alphabetically from a different viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have two scenes. Scene A is a tableview consisting of a list of fruits. Scene B has a segmented controller with one of the options to sort the fruit alphabetically.

scene A:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if  segue.identifier == "showFilter" {
        _ = segue.destinationViewController as! FilterViewController
    } 
}

?func alpheticalOrder(sender: AnyObject) { 
    fruits.sortInPlace({$0.name < $1.name }) } ?
```

scene B:

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FilterCell") as! FilterCell
        cell.segmentedController.addTarget(self, action: "segmentedControllerActionChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        return cell

    } 

    @IBAction func segmentedControllerActionChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        fruits.sortInPlace({$0.name < $1.name })
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "close:")
    greyView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func close(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

It's the `ViewController().tableView.reloadData()` line that is incorrect here, although I put it in to help understand what I'm trying to achieve.  Somehow I need to reload the tableview data to sort cells alphabetically by fruit name after exiting scene B to return to scene A.

Comment: Are you saying that SceneA is a ViewController and SceneB another ViewController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the line of code:

```
ViewController().tableView.reloadData()
```

That does not tell the existing `ViewController` to reload. The `ViewController()` creates a *new* instance of that view controller (which not connected to any storyboard scene; has no data; and will be immediately deallocated), and tells it to reload itself.

You need to have B refer to the existing A, not create a new one. Also, you presumably don't want to sort `fruits` in B, but rather back in A. Thus:

- add a property in B that points back to A:

  ```
  var sourceViewController: ViewControllerA!
  ```
- in the `prepareForSegue` of A, you have to set this property in B, e.g.:

  ```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if segue.identifier == "showFilter" {
          let filterViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FilterViewController
          filterViewController.sourceViewController = self
      } 
  }
  ```
- implement method in A that sorts the data and reloads the table:

  ```
  func sortFruitsAndReload() {
      fruits.sortInPlace {$0.name < $1.name }
      tableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```
- the `segmentedControllerActionChanged` in B should call that method in A:

  ```
  @IBAction func segmentedControllerActionChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
      if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
          sourceViewController.sortFruitsAndReload()
      }
  }
  ```

Or, even better, use a protocol to keep these two classes "weakly coupled" (i.e. opens the door to use this filter/sorting view controller in other situations):

- add a protocol in B:

  ```
  protocol FilterViewDelegate {
      func sortAndReload()
  }
  ```
- add a property in B to maintain reference to this `delegate`:

  ```
  var delegate: FilterViewDelegate?
  ```
- specify the A will conform to this protocol:

  ```
  class ViewControllerA: UIViewController, FilterViewDelegate { ... }
  ```

  clearly, keep the name of A's view controller class and base class to whatever you are using now, but just add `FilterViewDelegate` to the class declaration;
- implement method in A that sorts the data and reloads the table in order to satisfy the requirements of conforming to this protocol:

  ```
  func sortAndReload() {
      fruits.sortInPlace {$0.name < $1.name }
      tableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```
- in the `prepareForSegue` of A, you set this `delegate` property in B, e.g.

  ```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if segue.identifier == "showFilter" {
          let filterViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FilterViewController
          filterViewController.delegate = self
      } 
  }
  ```
- the `segmentedControllerActionChanged` in B should call that method in A.

  ```
  @IBAction func segmentedControllerActionChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
      if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
          delegate?.sortAndReload()
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Ahh so i could do  something like   func alpheticalOrder(sender: AnyObject) {
        fruits.sortInPlace({$0.name < $1.name })
    } in A and call it in scene B with the segmented controller?

Comment: Yes, but don't use that `ViewController()` syntax, as that's not referring to the existing A view controller, but creating (and discarding) yet another blank one. See revised answer.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense.  Works like an absolute gem, thanks!

Comment: Very good. BTW, I've added a more elegant solution (using delegate-protocol pattern rather than tighly coupling the filter view controller to the fruit view controller), too.

Comment: That's a pretty interesting alternative solution. I'll have to bookmark this to recap both solutions a few times. Thanks a lot!